# Hartshorne chapter V Exercise1.4(b): existence of nonsingular surface containing a straight line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The exercise is stated as follows:

> Assume $char(k)=0$, then show for every $d\ge 1$, there exists a nonsingular surface $X$ of degree $d$ in $\mathbb P^3$ containing the line $x=y=0$.

I have thought about using Bertini's theorem. I want to consider the $d$-uple embedding of $\mathbb P^3$ to some larger $\mathbb P^N$, then I just need to find a "good" hyperplane that intersects $\mathbb P^3$ nonsingular everywhere and contains the straight line. But the hyperplane such that the intersection containes $x=y=0$ form a closed subset of the hyperplane linear system $|H|$ in $\mathbb P^N$. In Bertini's theorem we just know the "good" hyperplanes form an open subset of the linear system... So I'm not sure whether this open subset intersects the closed subset.

Could you provide some help? Thanks!

Comment: Improved versions of Bertini that work for linear systems with a base locus exist in characteristic zero, but for this problem it's much faster to just go find the equation of a surface which works.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks! I have found it.